# Is there a lag time before notice of a new answer to a question appears?

Tags: support, user-interface

Before submitting an answer to a question I first check to see if there is a notice that a new answer has been submitted. However, on more than one occasion I have been embarrassed to submit an answer which is a virtual duplicate of an answer already submitted. Also, I frequently see essentially identical answers submitted by two people minutes apart so I assume the newer poster faced the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the load on the servers, the quality of your internet connection, and other circumstances the connection for real-time notifications can get interrupted.

If this happens you only see new answers once the page gets refreshed.

If you want to be sure, you can manually induce a refresh right before you post. (Be careful not to use your work in the process though! You could open a second copy of the question-thread it in a new tab for example.) But I do not think it is *necessary* to go that far; it's alright to have some redundancy.

For a question about the 'etiquette' of the situation see [About posting identical answers to a question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8191/about-posting-identical-answers-to-a-question)

Comment: AFAIK when a new answer is posted we are noticed by a pop-up message. (This happened to me for few times, so I think it's generally valid.)

Comment: Yes, usually this happens, but '[d]epending on the load on the servers, the quality of your internet connection, and other circumstances the connection for real-time notifications can get interrupted.'